# Excluding Portage/Gentoo post dependencies as runtime dependencies

Tags: gentoo, ebuild

The portage documentation defines [runtime dependencies and post dependencies](https://devmanual.gentoo.org/general-concepts/dependencies/) the latter of which can be merged after the current package and are used to resolve cyclic dependencies. The Emerge documentation also defines the **--onlydeps-with-rdeps** flag to get the run time [dependencies](https://dev.gentoo.org/%7Ezmedico/portage/doc/man/emerge.1.html).

Assuming I have the following sections in my ebuild file:

```
### My target ebuild file
RDEPEND="sys-some/dep-1.0-r1"
PDEPEND="sys-some/post-dep-1.0-r1"
```

If now run the following emerge command to get the list of runtime dependencies it pulls in the dependencies from *both* sections i.e. RDEPEND and PDEPEND:

```
emerge -pveo --onlydeps-with-rdeps=y --rebuild-if-new-rev=y --usepkg =sys-libs/my-target-1.0-r1
```

This will print out the following:

```
[ebuild R] sys-some/dep-1.0-r1
[ebuild R] sys-some/post-dep-1.0-r1
```

I only want the actual runtime dependencies, is there some way to achieve this without having to manually check the PDEPEND section and filter out the dependencies by hand?